# Printing Command Line Unicode Chess Board

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess, unicode

Let me preface this by detailing some of my design philosophy. The intent is to view the board from the perspective of the active player. Player moves are also factored into the design. When determining move logic, all that needs to happen is comparing against `'0'`. For checking the whiteness or blackness of a piece, `ord(c) % 265` should help by pulling the remainder and checking if it's in `range(4,10)` or `range(10,16)`. Anyway, any optimizations and critique is welcome! I'm particularly interested if it involves `numpy`, `scipy` | bitwise operators.

**chess.py**

```py
import numpy as np

chrs = {
    'b_checker': u'\u25FB',
    'b_pawn': u'\u265F',
    'b_rook': u'\u265C',
    'b_knight': u'\u265E',
    'b_bishop': u'\u265D',
    'b_king': u'\u265A',
    'b_queen': u'\u265B',
    'w_checker': u'\u25FC',
    'w_pawn': u'\u2659',
    'w_rook': u'\u2656',
    'w_knight': u'\u2658',
    'w_bishop': u'\u2657',
    'w_king': u'\u2654',
    'w_queen': u'\u2655'
}


def get_checkers():
    bw_row = [chrs['b_checker'], chrs['w_checker']]*4
    bw_checkers = []

    for i in range(8):
        bw_checkers.append(bw_row if i % 2 == 0 else bw_row[::-1])

    bw_checkers = np.array(bw_checkers)
    wb_checkers = bw_checkers[::-1]
    return {'W': wb_checkers, 'B': bw_checkers}


def get_board():

    def get_army(user):
        u = user.lower()
        guard = [chrs[u+'_rook'], chrs[u+'_knight'], chrs[u+'_bishop']]
        rear = guard + [chrs[u+'_king'], chrs[u+'_queen']] + guard[::-1]
        front = [chrs[u+'_pawn']]*8

        if user == 'B':
            return [rear, front]
        else:  # since white moves first
            return [front, rear]

    board = [squad for squad in get_army('B')]

    for _ in range(4):
        board.append(['0']*8)

    board += get_army('W')

    return np.array(board)


def print_board(board, checkers, user):
    chks = checkers[user]
    temp = board.copy() if user == 'W' else board.copy()[::-1]

    for i, row in enumerate(temp):
        for j, c in enumerate(row):
            print('', chks[i][j] if c == '0' else c, end='', flush=True)
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    checkers = get_checkers()
    board = get_board()
    user = 'W'
    print_board(board, checkers, user)
```

***Present Output:***

*White's Perspective*

[image: white]

> ```
> ♜ ♞ ♝ ♚ ♛ ♝ ♞ ♜
> ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟
> ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻
> ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼
> ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻
> ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼
> ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙
> ♖ ♘ ♗ ♔ ♕ ♗ ♘ ♖
> ```

*Black's Perspective*

[image: black]

> ```
> ♖ ♘ ♗ ♔ ♕ ♗ ♘ ♖
> ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙
> ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼
> ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻
> ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼
> ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻ ◼ ◻
> ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟
> ♜ ♞ ♝ ♚ ♛ ♝ ♞ ♜
> ```

Comment: The board should be with a white square in the bottom right corner, and the white king on the right, so the black representation is correct, the white one is mirrored. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess

Comment: @MaartenFabré Ah, I see now. The L-R diagonal should be black, while the R-L diagonal should be white. A 180 rotation should yield the same checker state.

Comment: I recommend using background/foreground color ANSI escape codes for terminal emulators

Comment: @MichałKrzysztofFeiler You mean using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492810/python-how-can-i-make-the-ansi-escape-codes-to-work-also-in-windows

Comment: @T145 yes that's what I meant

Comment: If you can output VT100 terminal codes (which most consoles allow), you can use background color codes to make the pieces appear on top of the appropriate white or black square.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## numpy

In this case there is no need to use. For an 8 by 8 board, filled with strings, there is no advantage to using it, apart from the possibility to index row and column at the same time

## enums

You have a few properties wich would be best presented as an `enum`. The color and the type of the piece

```
import enum


class Color(enum.Enum):
    WHITE = 0
    BLACK = 1


class Piece(enum.Enum):
    EMPTY = enum.auto()
    PAWN = enum.auto()
    ROOK = enum.auto()
    KNIGHT = enum.auto()
    BISHOP = enum.auto()
    KING = enum.auto()
    QUEEN = enum.auto()
```

## tuple

You have a `chrs` dictionary with keys that contain both the color and the piece. A better approach here would be to use tuples as keys

```
chrs = {
    (Color.WHITE, Piece.EMPTY): "\u25FB",
    (Color.WHITE, Piece.PAWN): "\u265F",
    (Color.WHITE, Piece.ROOK): "\u265C",
    (Color.WHITE, Piece.KNIGHT): "\u265E",
    (Color.WHITE, Piece.BISHOP): "\u265D",
    (Color.WHITE, Piece.KING): "\u265A",
    (Color.WHITE, Piece.QUEEN): "\u265B",
    (Color.BLACK, Piece.EMPTY): "\u25FC",
    (Color.BLACK, Piece.PAWN): "\u2659",
    (Color.BLACK, Piece.ROOK): "\u2656",
    (Color.BLACK, Piece.KNIGHT): "\u2658",
    (Color.BLACK, Piece.BISHOP): "\u2657",
    (Color.BLACK, Piece.KING): "\u2654",
    (Color.BLACK, Piece.QUEEN): "\u2655",
}
```

## board

You keep a black and a white board. Better would be to keep one board, and just flip it at the time of presentation.

```
def board_begin():
    return (
        [
            [
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.ROOK),
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.KNIGHT),
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.BISHOP),
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.QUEEN),
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.KING),
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.BISHOP),
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.KNIGHT),
                (Color.WHITE, Piece.ROOK),
            ],
            [(Color.WHITE, Piece.PAWN) for _ in range(8)],
            *[[None] * 8 for _ in range(4)],
            [(Color.BLACK, Piece.PAWN) for _ in range(8)],
            [
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.ROOK),
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.KNIGHT),
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.BISHOP),
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.QUEEN),
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.KING),
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.BISHOP),
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.KNIGHT),
                (Color.BLACK, Piece.ROOK),
            ],
        ]
    )
```

Here I use `None` to represent an empty tile, and replace it by a white or black tile at the time of display.

## flip board

If you use numpy to keep your board, you can `np.flip`, or a simple routine like this:

```
def flip(board):
    return [
        row[::-1] for row in reversed(board)
    ]
```

## display the board

Here a simple routine, which takes a boolean flag on whether to flip it:

```
def display_board(board, flip_board=False):
    for i, row in enumerate(board if not flip_board else flip(board)):
        row_strings = [
            chrs.get(tile, chrs[(Color((i + j) % 2), Piece.EMPTY)])
            for j, tile in enumerate(row)
        ]
        print("".join(row_strings))
```

using `dict.get` to replace the empty tiles by the correct squares

---

```
board = board_begin()
```

> ```
> [[(<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.ROOK: 3>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.KNIGHT: 4>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.BISHOP: 5>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.QUEEN: 7>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.KING: 6>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.BISHOP: 5>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.KNIGHT: 4>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.ROOK: 3>)],
>        [(<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.WHITE: 0>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>)],
>        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
>        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
>        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
>        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
>        [(<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.PAWN: 2>)],
>        [(<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.ROOK: 3>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.KNIGHT: 4>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.BISHOP: 5>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.QUEEN: 7>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.KING: 6>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.BISHOP: 5>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.KNIGHT: 4>),
>         (<Color.BLACK: 1>, <Piece.ROOK: 3>)]]
> ```

```
display_board(board, flip_board=False)
```

> ```
> ♜♞♝♛♚♝♞♜
> ♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
> ◻◼◻◼◻◼◻◼
> ◼◻◼◻◼◻◼◻
> ◻◼◻◼◻◼◻◼
> ◼◻◼◻◼◻◼◻
> ♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
> ♖♘♗♕♔♗♘♖
> ```

```
display_board(board, flip_board=True)
```

> ```
> ♖♘♗♔♕♗♘♖
> ♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
> ◻◼◻◼◻◼◻◼
> ◼◻◼◻◼◻◼◻
> ◻◼◻◼◻◼◻◼
> ◼◻◼◻◼◻◼◻
> ♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
> ♜♞♝♚♛♝♞♜
> ```

## Board class

If you want to incorporate moves etc, it might pay to make a Class of the board, with it's own display, `__getitem__` and move routines

Comment: Just wanted to note that your output of the grid is presently wrong. When flipped, the squares should be also, not just the main units.

Comment: depends on what you mean with flip. Your code just mirrors it along an axis, but doesn't do a 180° rotation. If you look at [a chess board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard#/media/File:Chess_board_opening_staunton.jpg), both black and white have a white square at their bottom right corner. For white the king is on the right, for black on the left, so I think my board is correct

Comment: I've added some pictures that should help w/ the visual reference. :)

Comment: When I test displaying the board w/ `flip=True`, I get a `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` for some reason.

Comment: I renamed the flag to `flip_board` to solve this

Answer (score 7):

## Piece dictionary

`chrs` is a very generic name. Since this is all about chess, you should be more specific by calling it something like `PIECES` or `ELEMENTS`. I chose to capitalize the name because you are using it as a module level constant, [which according to PEP8 should have capitalized names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants).

Also instead of `<color prefix>_<piece name>`, it might be more elegant to have a "two-stage" dictionary, like

```
ELEMENTS = {
    'b': {
        'checker': u'\u25FB',
        'pawn': u'\u265F',
        'rook': u'\u265C',
        'knight': u'\u265E',
        'bishop': u'\u265D',
        'king': u'\u265A',
        'queen': u'\u265B',
    },
    'w': {
        'checker': u'\u25FC',
        'pawn': u'\u2659',
        'rook': u'\u2656',
        'knight': u'\u2658',
        'bishop': u'\u2657',
        'king': u'\u2654',
        'queen': u'\u2655'
    }
}
```

Using this approach would help you to get rid of all the string concatenation in order to access the correct elements of the dictionary. With this approach the access would be like `ELEMENTS[<color prefix>][<piece name>]`.

## Magic values

There are a few magic values like `'B'`, `'W'`, or `'0'`. They should be replaced with module level constants or an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). From my experience this helps to avoid typos and makes it easier to change those values.

## Numpy

From the code shown in your question, I don't think Numpy is the right tool for the job here. Numpy can play its strengths mainly when applying uniform operations to larger "lumps" of numerical data. A 2-dimensional chessboard with 8x8 fields where you mainly perform operations at distinct locations is likely not a good match for this description. Since there is also quite some conversion between Python and Numpy data types, there is a good chance that this overhead will decrease the performance compared to plain Python code.

Answer (score 6):

*Python-specific* improvements:

- creating `bw_checkers` (in `get_checkers` function). Instead of appending repeatedly to previously created empty list:

  ```
  for i in range(8):
      bw_checkers.append(bw_row if i % 2 == 0 else bw_row[::-1])
  ```

  use *old-good* list comprehension:

  ```
  bw_checkers = [bw_row if i % 2 == 0 else bw_row[::-1] for i in range(8)]
  ```
- composing string keys in `get_army()` function. Formatted strings `f""` give a better visual perception:

  ```
  ...
  guard = [chrs[f'{u}_rook'], chrs[f'{u}_knight'], chrs[f'{u}_bishop']]
  ```
- **`get_board`** function. 
  Creating the initial board with `board = [squad for squad in get_army('B')]` is redundantly, but essentially the same as `board = get_army('B')`.
  Appending 4 rows of 8 `0`s with:

  ```
  for _ in range(4):
      board.append(['0'] * 8)
  ```

  is flexibly replaced with *list multiplication*:

  ```
  board += [['0'] * 8] * 4
  ```

  or `board += [['0'] * 8 for _ in range(4)]` - to avoid *cross-mutability* if those rows happen to be modified in further potential game
- `board.copy()` (in `print_board` function) is redundant as the `board` argument itself is created with `np.array(board)` (as new array)